# Cordova "Your network connection is offline. Reconnecting your network will close this popup."

Tags: android, cordova, cordova-plugins, sap-fiori

So, I have this problem with every (Android) phone I've used, when I am using SAP Fiori with Cordova, when I get to the login page it just has a popup that SAYS I'm not connected even though I know I am. Heck, the FioriClient from the app store even does this to me when I get to the Fiori login page.

I have testing this on multiple devices, multiple versions of Android, with crosswalk and without. I have no clue why it's doing this, and I build the base app using the SAP Fiori SDK so it has a lot of plugins like Logon and Network.

These are the plugins, I'm using plugman and am not sure how to list them, but this is the ls of the libs folder

```
AfariaProvider-3.8.0.jar        calendar-android-3.8.0.jar
AfariaSLL-7.00.6169.0.jar       corelibs-android-3.8.0.jar
ClientHubSLL-3.8.0.jar          e2etrace-android-3.8.0.jar
ClientLog-3.8.0.jar         encryptedstorage-android-3.8.0.jar
Common-3.8.0.jar            i18n-android-3.8.0.jar
CommonCertificateProvider-3.8.0.jar logger-android-3.8.0.jar
Connectivity-3.8.0.jar          maflogger-1.208.0.jar
CoreServices-3.8.0.jar          maflogoncore-1.208.0.jar
DataVaultLib-3.8.0.jar          maflogoncorecdvplugin-3.8.0.jar
E2ETrace-3.8.0.jar          online-android-3.8.0.jar
HttpConvAuthFlows-3.8.0.jar     perflib-1.2.0.jar
HttpConversation-3.8.0.jar      print-android-3.8.0.jar
Request-3.8.0.jar           sap-e2etrace-2.3.5.300.jar
SupportabilityFacade-3.8.0.jar      settingsexchange-android-3.8.0.jar
apppreferences-android-3.8.0.jar    simple-xml-2.7.1.jar
attachmentviewer-android-3.8.0.jar  support-v4-19.1.0.jar
authproxy-android-3.8.0.jar     toolbar-android-3.8.0.jar
barcodescanner-android-3.8.0.jar    voicerecording-android-3.8.0.jar
cachemanager-android-3.8.0.jar      zxing.core-3.0.0.jar
```